# Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [2,54], In[1]: [20,64]

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been getting this error and i cant figure out the reason. if anyone could help would be great. this is my code:

```
# Build the model
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(54,), activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.3))
model2.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.3))
model2.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.3))
model2.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.3))
model2.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.3))
model2.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model2.add(Dropout(0.3))
model2.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='output'))

# Adam optimizer with learning rate of 0.001
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
model2.compile(optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Neural Network Model2 Summary: ')
print(model2.summary())
log_dir = os.path.join('MID-logs', 'model-2-OneHot')
model_cbk = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
model_mckp = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_dir + '/Best-model-2.h5',  
                                            monitor='val_categorical_accuracy',  
                                            save_best_only=True, mode='max')   
history_2=model2.fit(x_train_one_hot, y, batch_size=64, epochs=200,validation_data=(x_val_one_hot, y_val))
test_combats_df = pd.read_csv('test_1.csv',header=None)  # 讀取訓練對戰數據
x_test_one_hot = pokemon_data_one_hot[test_combats_df -1].reshape((-1, 54))
x_test_one_hot[99]
test_one_hot_predicted = model.predict(x_val_one_hot[:2])
```

Ans this is the error i have been getting.

```
> InvalidArgumentError:  Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [2,54], In[1]:
> [20,64]    [[node sequential/dense/Relu (defined at
> <ipython-input-37-d57c9fbdfd7d>:1) ]]
> [Op:__inference_predict_function_635630]
> 
> Function call stack: predict_function
```

It looks like the problem is in Relu layer() function wherein somehow it is mad at not being able to multiply the same dimension of the matrix. But it is not clear how to solve the issue Thank you for the help in advance...

Comment: Can you add `x_train_one_hot.shape`?

Comment: `x_train_one_hot.shape`
`(40000, 54)`

Comment: Which code shows the error and is the model training working? You have not mentioned the defined callback inside the `model.fit()`. It seems the issue is with predictions. So please let us know the shape of `x_test_one_hot` or `x_val_one_hot` as well.